# map two ruby arrays together in sequence

Tags: arrays, ruby, math

I have these two arrays:

```
array1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
array2 = ['aaa','bbb','ccc']
```

I'm iterating over the first array:

```
array1.each do |item|
  puts "#{item} = #{<what I can't figure out>}"... 
end
```

I want to be able to assign the values of array2 sequentially to the values of array1 in the loop, so that the result of the block would be:

```
1 = 'aaa'
2 = 'bbb'
3 = 'ccc'
4 = 'aaa'
5 = 'bbb'
```

And so on so that the second array cycles through in sequence to the items in the first.

I don't math so well, but it seems like there would be a function that would do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this one

```
array1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
array2 = ['aaa','bbb','ccc'].cycle

array1.each do |item|
  puts "#{item} = #{array2.next}"
end
```

Comment: `array2` is perhaps not the best name for an enumerator. :-)

Comment: You're right :) Suggestions? We don't know its content

Comment: This works great! The variable names for the arrays are just examples. Thanks!

Comment: My pleasure Sir :)

Answer (score 1):

I prefer @Ursus' use of [Array#cycle](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-cycle), but you could also write the following.

```
arr1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
arr2 = ['aaa','bbb','ccc']

arr1.each_with_index { |item,i| puts "%i = %s" % [item, arr2[i % arr2.size]] }
1 = aaa
2 = bbb
3 = ccc
4 = aaa
5 = bbb
```

Answer (score 1):

`zip` could be useful here:

```
array1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
array2 = ['aaa','bbb','ccc']

puts array1.zip(array2.cycle).map { |n,s| "#{n} = #{s}" }
#1 = aaa
#2 = bbb
#3 = ccc
#4 = aaa
#5 = bbb
#=> nil
```

Answer (score 0):

if they are the same size:

```
array1.size.times do |i|
  puts "#{array1[i]} = #{array2[i]}"
end
```

Easy to read and can bring extend to `array3`, so on

Comment: I recommend you to use [`#each_index`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-each_index) or [`#each_with_index`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/each_with_index), but question is how to make it possible for arrays with different size :)

Answer (score 0):

Using modulo operator:

```
array1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
array2 = ['aaa','bbb','ccc']

for i in (0..(array1.count-1))
  puts "#{array1[i]} = #{array2[i % array2.count]}"
end
```

Comment: it will return `1 = aaa,
2 = bbb,
3 = ccc,
4 = aaa,
5 = bbb,
 = ccc`

Comment: Apologies. I did not see the '= ccc' in the terminal output. I have updated my answer to the one I would have given had I seen this.